# Attempting to run a PHP action when dropdown value is selected

Tags: php

I am attempting to echo out a new form dropdown menu IF a certain dropdown alternative is selected. This is the code I am running so far without results:

```
        <p><span>Hogskole</span><select id="selectbasic" name="Universitet"></p>


                        <option value=1>Høgskolen i Lillehammer</option>
                        <option value=2>Høgskolen i Gjøvik</option>
                        <option value=3>Høgskolen i Hedmark</option>

                 <?php switch($_POST['Universitet']){ 

                    case 'Høgskolen i Hedmark':
                    echo '<p><span>Hogskole</span><select name="Universitet"></p>
                            <option>Option One</option>
                            <option>Option Two</option>
                            <option>Option Three</option>';
                    break;

                    default:
                    break;

                 }
                 ?>
```

Comment: you cant get $_POST['Universitet'] value without submit a form

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` variable will hold the option value. Instead of

```
case 'Høgskolen i Hedmark':
```

use

```
case 3:
```

I usually avoid using numeric/ids values for select options, because they are very hard to be followed. You may consider changing it with a string, such as:

```
<select id="selectbasic" name="Universitet"></p>
    <option value="Lillehammer">Høgskolen i Lillehammer</option>
    <option value="Gjøvik">Høgskolen i Gjøvik</option>
    <option value="Hedmark">Høgskolen i Hedmark</option>
</select>
<?php 
  switch($_POST['Universitet']) { 
     case 'Hedmark':
         echo '<p><span>Hogskole</span><select name="Universitet">
                   <option>Option One</option>
                   <option>Option Two</option>
                   <option>Option Three</option>
               </select></p>';
         break;
     case 'Lillehammer':
     default:
         // echo something else
  }
?>
```

You may use this kind of behavior only if you submit the form to the current page, before provisioning data. Otherwise you must go and search about [javascript events](https://www.google.ro/search?q=javascript%20events).

Answer (score 0):

Php is not event driven language for client side handling you have to use jquery and AJAX

```
<script>
function changeState(){
var countryId='';
selectId=$("#selectbasic").val();
$.ajax({
   url: 'getStateList.php',
   type:'post',
   data: {
      selectId: selectId
   },   
   success: function(data) {
       $("#state").html(data);

   },
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can't do this thing without after select you submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST variable take option value.

```
So Use this code 

 case 3 :

Remove 
case 'Høgskolen i Hedmark':
```